# Disable Ctrl+Shift+0 on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, input-languages

I use apps that have functions bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, but Windows captures the keyboard shortcut. I have gone into the Advanced Settings and disabled the key sequence (similar to the [Vista steps](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967893)), but it still doesn't work.

Is there some other setting I have to disable?